# How to change the custom color of the theme “Frankfurt”?

Tags: beamer, themes

I am making some slides for a presentation, using the Winedt and using the theme `Frankfurt`. Can anyone suggest, how to change the color of the slide from purple to dark blue, or some more professional color?

I got the following slide, while running the following code:

```
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black, fg=sgibeet}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{purple!0}{white}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make -- as usual here -- your code snippet compilable, then we do not  have to guess what you are doing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default color of the frame title background using the `Frankfurt` theme already is a (dark) blue:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In your document, you overwrote this color using `\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=black, fg=sgibeet}`. To change the color from the purple (`sigibeet` in your case)  you could use something like `\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!50!black}` that yould result in the following output:

[image]